# Cocos2d-x crash: signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR) - Unable to open unknown symbol file

Tags: android, c++, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I've tried lots of different answers found here at SO but none are directly related with this "unknown symbol file".

This is my crash dump:

```
********** Crash dump: **********
Build fingerprint: 'samsung/ks01ltexx/ks01lte:4.4.2/KOT49H/I9506XXUCNG3:user/release-keys'
pid: 22578, tid: 22596, name: Thread-1821  >>> com.gamedev.game <<<
signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 00000000
Stack frame I/DEBUG   (  341):     #00  pc 00000000  <unknown>: Unable to open symbol file C:\proyects\game\proj.android\obj\local\armeabi/<unknown>. Error (22): Invalid argument
Stack frame I/DEBUG   (  341):     #01  pc 0035f169  /data/app-lib/com.gamedev.game-8/libgame.so (Java_org_cocos2dx_lib_Cocos2dxRenderer_nativeInit+100): Routine ft_lzw_file_init at ftlzw.c:?
Stack frame I/DEBUG   (  341):     #02  pc 00020bcc  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmPlatformInvoke+112)
Stack frame I/DEBUG   (  341):     #03  pc 00051927  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallJNIMethod(unsigned int const*, JValue*, Method const*, Thread*)+398)
Stack frame I/DEBUG   (  341):     #04  pc 000535d1  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmResolveNativeMethod(unsigned int const*, JValue*, Method const*, Thread*)+256)
Stack frame I/DEBUG   (  341):     #05  pc 0002a060  /system/lib/libdvm.so
Stack frame I/DEBUG   (  341):     #06  pc 00031510  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmMterpStd(Thread*)+76)
Stack frame I/DEBUG   (  341):     #07  pc 0002eba8  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInterpret(Thread*, Method const*, JValue*)+184)
Stack frame I/DEBUG   (  341):     #08  pc 00063e75  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallMethodV(Thread*, Method const*, Object*, bool, JValue*, std::__va_list)+336)
Stack frame I/DEBUG   (  341):     #09  pc 00063e99  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallMethod(Thread*, Method const*, Object*, JValue*, ...)+20)
Stack frame I/DEBUG   (  341):     #10  pc 00058b6b  /system/lib/libdvm.so
Stack frame I/DEBUG   (  341):     #11  pc 0000d298  /system/lib/libc.so (__thread_entry+72)
Stack frame I/DEBUG   (  341):     #12  pc 0000d430  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_create+240)
Crash dump is completed
```

Comment: it's null pointer exception in JNI code, run command `adb logcat | ndk-stack -sym {proj-dir}/obj/local/armeabi` to find out more detailed stack-trace

Comment: Thanks but that is what I did to receive this crash dump.

Comment: use `APP_OPTIM := debug` in `Applicatin.mk` for more detailed log information.

Answer (score 3):

Here's the clue:

```
pc 00000000
```

The PC (program counter) register is zero, meaning that the program is trying to execute code at address zero. There's no code there, hence the failure to display the function name.

It's probably caused by trying to call a null function pointer, or perhaps a virtual function on an invalid or corrupted object.

Comment: Thanks! It seems it can not find cocos_android_app_init(env, thiz), but it is there in jni/hellocpp/main.cpp and my C++ compilation is successful. And both env and thiz are not null, so I'm a bit lost.